# Is it possible to set the field focus to blur or focus in fillable PDF file form fields with python?

Tags: python, pdf, onblur

I am using pypdf2 in python to update form fields in pdfs with information in an excel table. I am able to do so using updatePageFormFieldValues.

The issue is encountered with the way the form is built. Some of the fields consist of drop down menus that are dependent on values found in specific fields. The loaded drop down menus work in a hierarchical manner:

Field 1: Drop down options ( blue, green)

Field 2: Drop down options (if Field1 = 'blue': one, two | if Field1 = 'green': eight, nine)
etc

By printing the pdf fields dictionary I can see the keys corresponding to each field:

*FIELD  :  {'/FT': '/Ch', '/T': 'FieldName', '/TU': '(Select from dropdown)', '/Ff': 131072, '/V': '(Select from dropdown)', '/AA': {'/Bl': IndirectObject(4133, 0)}}*

By doing some research I can see that the Field having a '/AA' key means there is an additional action linked to that field. The fact that '/AA' has a key of '/Bl', means the action is triggered when the field focus is blurred. That additional action must consist of the loading of different options in the drop down menus depending on the dependent field value.

By digging further into the document I can see that the additional action consists of some sort of embedded Javascript.

I am trying to work around the issue by:

1) setting the field focus to blur focus as I update the field values, or

2) somehow extract the content linked to '/Bl' and apply it to the document even if the field focus is not blurred.

So far I've been going around in circles and have no more clear direction.